# Indexing Python via arrays

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have an array `bound_1` `shape(1,5)`:

```
bound_1 = [ 0, 5, 9, 12, 14]
```

The array `bound_2` `shape(1, 5)`:

```
bound_2 = [ 5, 9, 12, 14, 19]
```

A value array, `shape(1, 5)`:

```
value = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

A result array, initialized with zeros, `shape(1, 19)`

```
result_array= [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now all I want to do is to write the value to its corresponding range (between bound1 and bound2) into result array, which should look then like

```
result_array= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

I thought it is done with:

```
result_array[ 0 , bound_1 : bound_2 ] = value
```

But I receive the error:

```
IndexError: Invalid Slice
```

I'm trying to solve this without a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution!

```
numpy.repeat ( value, bound_2-bound_1 )
```

[here is the documentation of that function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a cute "pythonic" way to answer this.  Perhaps someone else will be along with a shorter formulation.

But, the following should do the job:

```
for idx in range(0, len(bound_1)):
  for dst in range(bound_1[idx], bound_2[idx]):
    result_array[dst] = value[idx]
```

Comment: thank you very much! I totally try to solve this without for loop though..